# How to create wordpress category and subcategory for a custom post type?

Tags: php, wordpress

I created custom post type with a custom category, each category may or may not have subcategory and contain posts. I am confused with

1. parent category shows subcategory in front end, but when I goes to subcategory it will only display that category name. I want to display all the siblings and parent category on each category page side, then the user can goes to each category page by simply clicking on each category.
2. all these were display in archive page. can we create a custom page for displaying it

Answer (score 0):

1. If you don't have any custom posts that have the subcategory assigned to them(?) there will be nothing on that page. Perhaps using a custom taxonomy template will help you solve this problem.
2. Assuming your custom post name is 'cpt' and your custom taxonomy name is 'cptax', you can tell Wordpress to use different files to display these collections just by naming them archive-cpt and taxonomy-cptax. https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/